# Printing With Custom Header

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a document and at the end of the document I want to set the printing specifics as part of the macro.

What I want is to fit all the columns to one page (but not the rows), and freeze the top 3 rows so when the second page prints the top 3 rows appear on the second page as well (this is the part I´m having issues with).

My code (below) includes (what I believe to be) everything except the freezing of the top three rows part

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
 .Orientation = xlLandscape
 .Zoom = False
 .FitToPagesWide = 1
 .FitToPagesTall = False
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add it to your current code use the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     .Orientation = xlLandscape
     .Zoom = False
     .FitToPagesWide = 1
     .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$3"
End With
```

to manually do it do this:

[image]

Do this and you should get thwe results you are asking for:

Go to Page Layout, then the sheets tab and set the Rows to repeat at top

Comment: There is a button on the Page Layout tab to go directly to Print Titles (the Sheet tab).

Comment: ^ We developers are always like this, we always do it the hard way. JK :p

Answer (score 0):

If you *record a macro* in Excel that uses the Page Layout tab, Print Titles option, you obtain code like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$3"
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
```

Merge the two important lines with your current code.